# How can i invoke powershell that uses "graphical command window" (show-command) from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

```
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput;
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {               
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Show-Command -name Get-Content -PassThru");
                PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();             
            }
```

This return no output but there is an error on PowerShellInstance whose error stream has a null reference exception

> at
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.GetHostWindow(PSCmdlet
>   cmdlet)    at
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.CallShowDialog(PSCmdlet
>   cmdlet)    at
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.ShowCommandWindow(PSCmdlet
>   cmdlet, Object commandViewModelObj, Double windowWidth, Double
>   windowHeight, Boolean passThrough)

Comment: Judging from a quick look at decompiled code, it is a bug which requires that [`PSHost.PrivateData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.host.pshost.privatedata.aspx) of used PowerShell host to return not `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your code:

```
        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput;
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create()) {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Show-Command -name Get-Content -PassThru");
            PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            if (!PowerShellInstance.HadErrors ) {
                foreach (var item in PSOutput) {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            } else {
                foreach (var item in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error) {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Exception.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

returns this output

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.GetHostWindow(PSCmdlet cmdlet)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.CallShowDialog(PSCmdlet cmdlet)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandInternal.ShowCommandHelper.ShowCommandWindow(PSCmdlet cmdlet, Object commandViewModelObj, Double windowWidth, Double windowHeight, Boolean passThrough)
```

Which is pretty much is indicating that there's no HostWindow object, which is to be expected using the PS Management Objects.

Using ILSpy to examine the code in `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll` it appears that the `Show-Command` cmdlet invokes a `ShowCommandProxy` object that is looking for a System.Management.Automation.Internal `GraphicalHostReflectionWrapper` object, which is not set.

--Update--

I'd take a look at this question: [Custom PSHostUserInterface is ignored by Runspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163980/custom-pshostuserinterface-is-ignored-by-runspace) which show that you're going to have to implement your own PSHost (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshost(v=vs.85).aspx) and implement your own `PSHostUserInterface` and finally your own `PSHostRawUserInterface` to handle all the I/O.

MS has an example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706551(v=vs.85).aspx that does a custom host implementation.

Comment: Yes i saw that also https://github.com/stangelandcl/pash-1/blob/master/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands/ShowCommandCommand.cs

The Question is it possible to set it via the runspace or something. the ISE seems to manage it.

Comment: The HOST06 code from MS (here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-PowerShell-Host06-3a069fdb/view/SourceCode) throws the same error with `Show-Command`.   Interestingly, `'fred' | out-gridview` works with both your code and Host06.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the parameters of a PowerShell CmdLet, you can use Get-Command.  You will not be able to show a PowerShell graphical window from C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cmdLetName = "Get-Content";
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput;
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Get-Command");
                PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("Name", cmdLetName);
                PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            }

            foreach(var item in PSOutput)
            {
                var cmdLetInfo = item.BaseObject as System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo;
                var defaultParamSet = cmdLetInfo.ParameterSets.Where(pSet => pSet.IsDefault == true).FirstOrDefault();

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Default ParameterSet for {0}.  (*) Denotes Mandatory", cmdLetName));
                foreach (var param in defaultParamSet.Parameters.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsMandatory))
                {
                    if (param.IsMandatory)
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\t {0} (*)", param.Name));
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\t {0}", param.Name)); ;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Default ParameterSet for Get-Content.  (*) Denotes Mandatory
     Path (*)
     ReadCount
     TotalCount
     Tail
     Filter
     Include
     Exclude
     Force
     Credential
     Verbose
     Debug
     ErrorAction
     WarningAction
     InformationAction
     ErrorVariable
     WarningVariable
     InformationVariable
     OutVariable
     OutBuffer
     PipelineVariable
     UseTransaction
     Delimiter
     Wait
     Raw
     Encoding
     Stream
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/16/use-the-get-command-powershell-cmdlet-to-find-parameter-set-information/

Comment: Yeah that would be other way but i was trying to avoid having to skin my own UI just to get some default args from the user. Must be a way to recreate console behavior from c#.

Comment: What's your end goal/usage for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug for me. `Show-Command` does not check [`PrivateData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.host.pshost.privatedata.aspx) for `null` before accessing its properties. To work around this you need to implement your own `PSHost` and `override` `PrivateData` to return not `null` object:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Management.Automation.Host;
    public class NotDefaultHost : PSHost {
        private Guid instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        private PSObject privateData = new PSObject();
        public override CultureInfo CurrentCulture {
            get {
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            }
        }
        public override CultureInfo CurrentUICulture {
            get {
                return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            }
        }
        public override Guid InstanceId {
            get {
                return instanceId;
            }
        }
        public override string Name {
            get {
                return "NonDefaultHost";
            }
        }
        public override PSObject PrivateData {
            get {
                return privateData;
            }
        }
        public override PSHostUserInterface UI {
            get {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public override Version Version {
            get {
                return new Version(1, 0);
            }
        }
        public override void EnterNestedPrompt() {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override void ExitNestedPrompt() {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override void NotifyBeginApplication() { }
        public override void NotifyEndApplication() { }
        public override void SetShouldExit(int exitCode) { }
    }
’@

$Runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace((New-Object NotDefaultHost));
$Runspace.Open()
$PS=[PowerShell]::Create()
$PS.Runspace = $Runspace;
$PS.AddScript('Show-Command -Name Get-Content -PassThru').Invoke()
if($PS.HadErrors) {
    '--- Errors: ---'
    $PS.Streams.Error
}
$PS.Dispose()
$Runspace.Dispose()
```